# Does friction depend on the area between bodies thats in contact?

Tags: friction

Does [friction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction) depend on the area between bodies thats in contact? If yes why we make threads on vehicles tires and below shoes? Does it not cause reduce in friction?

Comment: Effectively covered in http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16213/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29903/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41576/, I think.